# MongoCursor is extremely slow

Tags: c#, mongodb

We have a collection (called childData) with the following indexes:

```
childDataCollection.CreateIndex(IndexKeys.Ascending(MongoChildData.ItemIdProperty).Ascending(MongoChildData.ChildIdProperty));
childDataCollection.CreateIndex(IndexKeys.Ascending(MongoChildData.RedundantTimeProperty));
```

There are about 20 million records in the database. This query:

```
MongoCursor<MongoChildData> childCursor = childDataCollection.FindAll();              
childCursor.SetFields(Fields.Include(MongoChildData.ItemIdProperty, MongoChildData.ChildIdProperty));  
childCursor.SetFlags(QueryFlags.NoCursorTimeout);            
childCursor.SetBatchSize(1000);

foreach (MongoChildData childData in childCursor)            
{     
}
```

Is taking days to interate over all these records.

Given that the index covers the two fields how can this take so long? It takes about 3 minutes to get each batch of a 1000 records.

We are using the C# driver version 2.4.4.4. Please note that running the query on the actual MongoDB is extremely slow so this does not look like a driver issue.

Comment: Way too broad, but also almost certainly nothing to do with programming. The .NET driver is in use by a lot of applications, so there is no driver issue that you just stumbled upon yourself. Indexes here are irrelevant since `FindAll()` has **no query** and is simply fetching everything from the collection, and even with "projected fields" you did not exclude the `_id` property and thus this would still not be a **covered query**. Your issue is almost certainly networking related and thus best discussed on a different site.

Comment: I am running this application on the same server that is running the instance of Mongo so it is not network related. I want to return everything from the collection - that is the idea.

Comment: Doing this:             childCursor.SetFields(Fields.Exclude(MongoItem.IdProperty).Include(MongoChildData.ItemIdProperty, MongoChildData.ChildIdProperty));
made no difference by the way